# add polylines from web service to R leaflet map

Tags: r, leaflet

I am trying to add polylines from a web service to an R leaflet map. I tried using addWMSTiles. I didn't get an error, but also the lines didn't show up.

Info on the web service source is here: https://mapcase.deq.idaho.gov/arcgis/rest/services/ID305B_2016_WMS/MapServer/14

```
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

leaflet() %>%
  setView(lat = 46.2271, lng = -116.00293, zoom = 7) %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldTopoMap") %>%
addWMSTiles("https://mapcase.deq.idaho.gov/arcgis/rest/services/ID305B_2016_WMS/MapServer/14", layers = "2016 305(b) Lakes (Final) (ID:14)", options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. R package [leaflet.esri](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leaflet.esri/leaflet.esri.pdf) provides tools for mapping ESRI web services data with leaflet. A minimal example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.esri)

leaflet() %>%
  setView(lat = 46.2271, lng = -116.00293, zoom = 7) %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldTopoMap") %>%
  addEsriFeatureLayer(url = paste0("https://mapcase.deq.idaho.gov/arcgis/rest/services/ID305B_2016_WMS/MapServer/14"),
                      useServiceSymbology = TRUE, weight = 1, fill = FALSE, 
                      labelProperty = "ENTITY_ID", labelOptions = labelOptions(textsize = "12px"), options = featureLayerOptions(useCors = FALSE))
```